# How to add RadioButton and CheckBox on iPhone using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I checked with Interface Builder and UI components. But there is no RadioButton and CheckBox. Is there some other way to add these components? Im using MonoTouch for developing iPhone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Radio buttons, you can use one of:

- UISegmentedControl
- Dedicated rows in a UITableView controller for the options
- Roll your own

For quick in-line stuff, use the UISegmentedControl, when this is more of a new context or there are too many options, use a nested UITableView control that you push from your UINavigationController, if there are only a handful of options, you can just dedicate a couple of rows in your UITableView to the radio options and run it yourself.

MonoTouch.Dialog (my own external library) provides an easy way to create UITableView controllers, and in particular radio-button like functionality like the ones that you create with UITableView solutions.

For checkboxes, you can use a decoration on your UITableView cell, or you can use sliders controls for "on/off" settings.

Again, if you go with the UItableView approach, MonoTouch.Dialog does most of this for you.

Download the code and samples from:

http://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Answer (score 1):

yes friend for this you have to add a image 
in  .h file

```
int editCount;  
int check;

in viewdidload{

editCount = 0;
    check = 0;
}

if( check == 0 )
    {       
        UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

        if (editCount%2 == 0) {
            [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:160] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TICKIMAGE",[selectedButton tag]] ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else {

            [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:160] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PLAINBUTTON",[selectedButton tag]] ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       

}

editcount++;
}
```

this work similar to radio button u have to use tickimage and plainbutton image there ..ok friend

Comment: if this helps please do upvote.Your upvote increase our strength to keep posting our answers

Comment: How we can achieve with MonoTouch?

Comment: plz explain a little friend . you can use touch move and begin

Comment: I used MonoTouch C# for developing iPhone application. Im asking on Monotouch c#.